# Sort NSMutableArray is same order as another NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c

I'm using a `NSMutableArray *allObjectsArray;` with dictionaries to fill a Table View with content.

Now I want to use a second `NSMutableArray *userDataArray;` (also with dictionaries) to display some user defined data in the same TableView.

To make a way for the dictionaries from the different arrays to recognize each other, they both have a string with key: `"Name"` with matching values.

So how can I write a code so that the `userDataArray` objects are in the same order as the `allObjectsArray` objects using the matching values from the `"Name"` key?

So when the cells are created, the `[allObjectsArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]` should now reprecent the same object as `[userDataArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just associate the objects in *userDataArray* to the objects in *allObjectsArray* directly? For example, each object in *allObjectsArray* can have a *userData* field that points to the associated object in *userDataArray*

In any case, if you really want to sort them you can do this:

```
NSArray * descriptors = @[ [ NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES ] ] ;
allObjectsArray = [ allObjectsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors ] ;
userDataArray = [ allObjectsArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors ] ;
```

**EDIT: To directly associate the dictionaries from *userDataArray* with those in *allObjectsArray***

For each object in *allObjectsArray*, since they're dictionaries, you can just do this

```
NSDictionary * dictionaryFromAllObjectsArray = ...
[ dictionaryFromAllObjectsArray setObject:associatedUserObject forKey:@"userObject" ]
```

Now they're associated...

Later:

```
NSDictionary * dictionaryAtIndex = [ allObjectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ] ;
NSDictionary * userDictionaryAtIndex = [ dictionaryAtIndex objectForKey:@"userObject" ] ;
```

Comment: This is new to me, if you could give some kind of example or reference for making this?

Comment: Also, in obj-c land, keys are usually lower case: `@"name"` instead of `@"Name"`

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to restructure your data so that you only have a single dictionary for any name and it combines the objects and keys that you currently have in your pair of dictionaries.  That would mean only needing one array and once it's sorted you have the rows you need.

Comment: Ok that's how I did it first. But let's say if I later decide to make a change of the "price" value in some of the dictionaries. Will I be able replace only the changed strings, without reset of the user defined strings or anything else? Now my app only checks if the plist exists in documents directiory and write if not. Can I say: if plist exists, look for changes in some specified strings and replace only those?

Comment: The key value pairs in a dictionary are independent of each other